# ZF3 optional parameter with child routes on Segment class doesn't want to match

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I want to create routes with an optional [lang] parameter that would be used to set the application language as follows:

**Example with default lang param(EN for example)**

```
domain.tld/
domain.tld/users
domain.tld/contacts
etc.
```

**Example witt new lang param(DE for examle)**

```
domain.tld/de
domain.tld/de/users
domain.tld/de/contacts
etc.
```

This is my route configuration:

```
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'site' => [
            'type' => Segment::class,
            'options' => [
                'route' => '[/:lang]',
                'constraints' => [
                    'lang' => '[a-z]{2}',
                ],
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                    'action' => 'index',
                    'lang' => 'en',
                ],
            ],
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => [
                'home' => [
                    'type' => Literal::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'route' => '/',
                        'defaults' => [
                            'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                            'action' => 'index',
                        ],
                    ],
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                ],
                'application' => [
                    'type' => Segment::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'route' => '/application[/:action]',
                        'defaults' => [
                            'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                            'action' => 'index',
                        ],
                    ],
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

When I have lang param in the url everything is fine. But when I try to open "default" lang without specifying it into the path (ex. example.tld/application/test) it gives me 404 error.

What I found is that the final regex after transformation from Segment class is `(\G(?:/(?P<param1>([a-z]{2})))?)` and path is `/application/test`. When `preg_match` is executed on Segment.php:385 it return match with following values:

```
[
    '0' => '/ad',
    'param1' => 'ad',
    '1' => 'ad',
],
```

which is obviously the wrong behavior. My language is set to "ad" instead of open application/test action. I tested around 10 more regex but without success... (ex. `^[a-z]{2}$`).

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get 404 because URL does not match `site` route, so child routes of `site` are skipped.
Try this:

```
        'home' => [
            'type' => Segment::class,
            'options' => [
                'route' => '/[:lang/]',
                'constraints' => [
                    'lang' => '(en|de)?',
                ],
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                    'action' => 'index',
                    'lang' => 'en',
                ],
            ],
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => [
                'application' => [
                    'type' => Segment::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'route' => 'application[/:action]',
                        'defaults' => [
                            'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                            'action' => 'index',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]
```

If you do not provide lang param then it takes default (`en` in my example) param.
Example:

> example.tld/application/test

- `lang` is `en`
- `controller` is `IndexController`
- `action` is `test` (`testAction()`)

> example.tld/de/application/test

- `lang` is `de`
- `controller` is `IndexController`
- `action` is `test` (`testAction()`)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works like that but my issue is that I add the languages in the db so they're dynamically created and can't be hardcoded in constraints array. So I need to match excactly 2 characters or none(for default). Maybe regex is wrong? I tried to match also empty string like that `[a-z]{2}|^$` but also didn't work. I hope you understand what is my need?

Comment: Are you talking about `'constraints' => ['lang' => '(en|de)?']`? You can change `(en|de)?` to `[a-z]{2}` and it will work. I have checked on clean Zend Skeleton project.

Comment: Yes, I found what's the problem. My child routes has prepended slash and it's not possible to match the route with it. Everything's great, but is that a way to use slash in child routes instead of parent. `[/:lang]`? I need that because my app can choose between subomain language style or path style so I can choose base route to mentoined above or to `'type' => Hostname::class,
            'options' => [
                'route' => '[:lang.]framework.dev',
            ],` , but I can't use slash inside Hostname rotue and If i didn't set the slash in child route it will brake Hostname route..

Comment: How do you choose between subdomain or path lang? Can't you set lang with slash if app use path style and lang without slash if app use subdomain? What I mean is to create two types of route. First one with path style, second one with subdomain path and use specific route depending on app settings